# How to rewrite path in nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, web-config, cors

I have following url

```
http://localhost:3000/aws/abc/pqr/xyz/example.png
```

I want it to redirect to

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/abc/pqr/xyz/example.png
```

I tried following in nginx.conf

```
location /aws {
  rewrite ^/aws/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_redirect off;        
  proxy_pass  https://s3.amazonaws.com;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your rewrite statement. Try: `rewrite ^/aws/?(.*)$ /$1 break;`?

Comment: Sorry it was just a typo, i just changed but it still not working getting `http://localhost:3000/aws/abc/pqr/xyz/example.png` only. I am using it in `img` tag & my image is not getting loaded. Actually i am trying this as i am geeting `CORS` issue while loading the image.

Comment: Can you post the complete conf?